# How to change the default time format in ionic-datetime?

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I know the default time format for 24hrs is 0 to 23, but I want to convert into 1 to 24. I know ionic-datetime provides hourValues properties for this but its not working in this case its omitting the value after 23.

I followed this [document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime/#month-names-and-day-of-the-week-names).

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" pickerFormat="HH mm" hourValues="01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24"></ion-datetime>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As your question tag suggests, you should visit **Ionic v3** docs instead of the Ionic last version documentation because there are substantial changes between them! :)

Now, talking about the `hourValues` property, the documentation says:

> By default the hour values range from 0 to 23 for 24-hour, or 1 to 12
> for 12-hour. However, to control exactly which hours to display, the
> hourValues input can take either an array of numbers, or string of
> comma separated numbers.

It means you can control which hours to display, and these hours understand a range between 0 to 23, but **you can never add new numbers to the list** like 24, 25, etc.